# How to stop http connection with google maps while testing (Python)

Tags: python, google-maps, testing

I am writing some unit tests in python to tests some functionalities of my website. The website uses google maps in some parts of it. Whenever I test I get the following in the terminal:

```
..........[2014-06-27 13:20:23,018] [INFO] - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): maps.google.com
.[2014-06-27 13:20:23,277] [INFO] - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): maps.google.com
.[2014-06-27 13:20:23,590] [INFO] - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): maps.google.com
[2014-06-27 13:20:23,811] [INFO] - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): maps.google.com
.[2014-06-27 13:20:24,061] [INFO] - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): maps.google.com
.[2014-06-27 13:20:24,384] [INFO] - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): maps.google.com
[2014-06-27 13:20:24,654] [INFO] - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): maps.google.com
....
```

I also get the right output and the tests run okay, but is there any way to stop this from appearing or close the connection while testing (something permanent for tests perhaps?)? I think I can use the Mocking and Testing library, but is there a simpler way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use mocking, then write a "stub" Google Maps server. This server obeys the same Google Maps API, but just returns canned data, and runs locally.  Then configure your program to use 'localhost' vs 'maps.google.com'.